# Can't formulate the response object for SOAP Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, soap, wsdl, quickbooks

I'm writing a SOAP Node.js webservice using [node-soap](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap) and I can't figure out how to formulate the response correctly.

I'm integrating a webapp with QuickBooks 2013 using the [Web Connector](http://marketplace.intuit.com/webconnector/). The client will make the request to authenticate and I can log the arguments passed so i know that it is being called, but I can't get the the response correct.

The documentation says it is expecting an array of strings as the response.
The relevant parts of the WSDL look like:

```
  <s:element name="authenticateResponse">
    <s:complexType>
      <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="authenticateResult" type="tns:ArrayOfString" />
      </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
  </s:element>

  <s:complexType name="ArrayOfString">
    <s:sequence>
      <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="string" nillable="true" type="s:string" />
    </s:sequence>
  </s:complexType>

 <wsdl:message name="authenticateSoapOut">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:authenticateResponse" />
</wsdl:message>

<wsdl:operation name="authenticate">
  <wsdl:input message="tns:authenticateSoapIn" />
  <wsdl:output message="tns:authenticateSoapOut" />
</wsdl:operation>

 <wsdl:operation name="authenticate">
  <soap:operation soapAction="http://developer.intuit.com/authenticate" style="document" />
  <wsdl:input>
    <soap:body use="literal" />
  </wsdl:input>
  <wsdl:output>
    <soap:body use="literal" />
  </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
```

I have tried many different ways of configuring the response object but keep getting errors from the client (QuickBooks Web Connector)

The JavaScript I have is :

```
    var myService = {
          'QBWebConnectorSvc': {
              'QBWebConnectorSvcSoap': {
                  authenticate: function(args) {

                           //i have tried many variations of nesting arrays/objects etc.
                    var toReturn = {
                        "ArrayOfString":[guid()," "," "," "]
                    };
                    return toReturn;
                  }
              }
          }
      }

     var xml = require('fs').readFileSync('qbwc.wsdl', 'utf8'),
          server = http.createServer(function(request,response) {
              response.end("404: Not Found: "+request.url)
          });

    server.listen(8000);

    soap.listen(server, '/wsdl', myService, xml);
```

Somehow I need to build the "ArrayOfString" but I have no idea how to do it; I am new to the whole soap thing.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: @JohnB I actually dont remember, I decided to use keithpalmers php framework and just make submit endpoint that I call from node and both applications talk to the same database.

Comment: thinking back it would never authenticate

Comment: You're probably no longer interested, but for anyone else stumbling upon this: QBWC does not like the XML response that node-soap creates for arrays. I have confirmed this by hijacking the dynamically created response and instead hard coding what it _[should be](http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_web_connector_soap_authenticate)_. I'm working on getting a better understanding of how node-soap creates the XML so that I can amend it to send what QBWC is expecting. I'll certainly post an answer here when I get it working.

Comment: I've just spent the last week wrestling with `node-soap`'s namespacing strategy, I completely re-wrote the WSDL parser from the ground up to get a handle on it.  But I'm not writing a server, I don't know if that's the same issue you're experiencing, but it seems likely.  The way in which `node-soap` converts an object literal into XML is fairly straight forward, it's the namespacing that is not.

Comment: @Jason thanks for your input. It was indeed a namespace issue, got it sorted out without having to modify node-soap's `objectToXML` function in any way (thankfully!)

Comment: The `objectToXML` function doesn't provide a way to assign a namespace to any element nested further down than the first child of the body element, nor does it allow you to set more than one namespace on that first child.  That was a critical limitation in my application, but it looks like it's not for QuickBooks.

Answer (score 5):

### Short answer:

Your authenticate function should look like this:

```js
authenticate: function(args) {
    return {
        authenticateResult: { string: [guid(), {}] }
    };
}
```

### Explanation:

There are a couple things wrong with your code, I'll post the error messages for each to make them more searchable for anyone having the same problem in the future.

#### QBWC1012: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

You should be returning `authenticateResult` within the object, not `ArrayOfString`.

#### QBWC1012: Authentication failed due to following error message. Index was outside the bounds of the array.

QBWC does not like the XML response that node-soap creates for arrays. Here's (the relevant part of) what node-soap produces if you return an array within an object (i.e. `return { authenticateResult: [guid(), ""] }`:

```xml
<tns:authenticateResponse xmlns:tns="http://developer.intuit.com/" xmlns="http://developer.intuit.com/">
    <tns:authenticateResult>bdaa63cf-2d26-4d6b-8a54-6f519af6e8d4</tns:authenticateResult>
</tns:authenticateResponse>
```

And here is what QBWC is expecting:

```xml
<tns:authenticateResponse xmlns:tns="http://developer.intuit.com/" xmlns="http://developer.intuit.com/">
    <tns:authenticateResult>
        <tns:string>bdaa63cf-2d26-4d6b-8a54-6f519af6e8d4</tns:string>
        <tns:string></tns:string>
    </tns:authenticateResult>
</tns:authenticateResponse>
```

The first problem is the namespace is wrong. The second is node-soap skips over the empty string and does not include it in the response, but QBWC is looking for it (hence the index out of bounds). The hack-ish solution I've posted will address both these problems:

- Adding an array with `string` as its key within the `authenticateResult` object will correct the namespace
- An empty object instead of an empty string will *not* be overlooked by node-soap's `objectToXML` parser.

Comment: This answer just saved me hours of frustration,  thanks! Expect a big reward soon. :-)

Comment: Enjoy your reputation, you deserve it! :-)